# Minor taking written exam

Tags: ppl, faa-knowledge-test, exams

Does anyone know if a parent/guardian needs to be present for any reason in order for a 16 year old to take the FAA written exam? Or are there any other technicalities/considerations when it comes to a minor taking the written exam?

It seems like the answer is "No", but I'm just making sure...

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[FAA Order 8080.6H - Conduct of Airman Knowledge Tests](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/FAA_Order_8080.6H.pdf) states, on page 3-2, the following with respect to an "Underage Applicant" (under age 18):

> **Underage Applicant**. For an applicant under the age of 18, a parent or legal guardian **may**
> have to accompany the applicant and, after identifying themselves as described above, may attest
> to the applicant’s identity. (Refer to FAA Order 8900.1, Volume 5, Chapter 1, Section 3.) The
> parent or legal guardian must present a valid and current form of identification as described in
> subparagraph 1b above.

*(emphasis is mine)*

That a parent or legal guardian **may**
have to accompany the applicant  is likely due to the fact that the applicant (under age 18) may not possess a required form of identification, such as that noted on page 3-1 in FAA  Order 8080.6H (link above):

> **Acceptable Forms of Identification**. The proof of applicant identification may be
> presented in more than one form.
>
> > (1) Acceptable forms of photo identification for U.S. citizens and resident aliens include:
> >
> > > • Driver’s license issued by a U.S. state or territory,
>
> > > • U.S. Government identification card,
>
> > > • U.S. Military identification card, or

> > > • Passport or alien residency card

Comment: That was my understanding, only if the minor doesn't have a passport or drivers license would a parent need to be present.  I also found this from the link below: "In the case of an applicant under the age of 18, who does not possess an acceptable form(s) of
identification, a parent or legal guardian is required to accompany the applicant, and after presenting
identification as described in the above table, may attest to the applicant’s identity" https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/2022-09/testing_matrix_2.pdf